# The process for contribution to git packages?

Tags: ruby, git, open-source, github

Until now I have only used git packages with gem:

```
gem install <package>
```

Haven't contributed to correcting things to git-hub.

I wonder how you all do it?

Eg. when I have installed the gem package, should I manually create a folder where I do:

```
git clone <repo>
```

Then when I find the gem package behaving strangely, I just correct the source in that repo of mine, and then I push it to git-hub?

Is that the process? Or is the source already there somewhere when I installed it?

Share your experiences so others know how to contribute, preferably in steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to contribute to a project that uses Git, then yes, you should clone the repository, commit your changes to the clone, and then push the changes back.

Comment: And then send a pull request to the maintainer

Comment: @Isaac. Shouldn't the maintainer issue a checkout instead of pull? According to this pic http://osteele.com/images/2008/git-transport.png  to get data from the local repo you do a checkout, isn't the data in the maintainers local repo when I have pushed my changes? Or do you mean that he pulls form my remote repo (if so, what if im not online)?

Comment: I didn't mean a literal git pull; "pull request" is a github term. See http://github.com/guides/pull-requests

Comment: Note that if you want to submit a pull request, you should do your work on a separate branch.